# How to return most frequent element in BinaryTree in Java

Tags: java, exception, max, binary-tree, stack-overflow

I want to return number of values that is the most frequently in BinaryTree. I have BinaryClass which contain a lot of methods as add, contain, isEmpty, counter, iterator and other.I tried to implement this method `public int getMaxFrequency()` but I get a problem StackOverFlowException at markerd row.

When I run my code I get **StackOverFlow Exception**, anyone can help me please,

I'm new in BinaryTree.

Help me please.

```
enter code here
public class TreeSetCounter<T extends Comparable<T>> implements    Iterable<T>{
public Node<T> root; 
int size;
int count=0;

public TreeSetCounter() {
    root = null;
    size = 0;
   }
 public int counter(T t) {
 return counterRecursive(root, t);
  }

   public int counterRecursive(Node<T> root, T t) {
   int count = 0;
   if(root == null) {
        return 0;
          }
    if(root.value.equals(t)) {
      count++; 
      }
   count = count + counterRecursive(root.left, t)+           counterRecursive(root.right, t);
   return count; }


 public int getMaxFrequency(){
 
  return inorder(root);           
  }

  public int inorder( Node<T> prev) {
 
    int count = 1, max = 0;
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;}
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    inorder(root.left);   // I get the Exception att this row code.
    while (prev != null) {
    if (root.value == prev.value)
            count++;
        else
            count = 1;
    }
    
    if (count > max) {
        max = count;
        list.clear();
        list.add(root.value);
    } else if (count == max) {
        list.add(root.value);
    }
    prev = root;
    inorder(root.right);
    return max;
}

enter code here
Node.java
public class Node <T>{
T value;
int counter;
Node<T> left;
Node<T> right;

Node(T value, int count) {
    this.value = value;
    right = null;
    left = null;
    this.counter= count;
    }

enter code here
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSetCounter <String> tsc= new TreeSetCounter<String>();
    tsc.add("java");
    tsc.add("java");
    tsc.add("not");
    tsc.add("cool");
    tsc.add("java");
    tsc.add("is");
    tsc.add("java");
    tsc.add("good");
    System.out.println(tsc.getMaxFrequency());}
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing some steps.  Are there specific `classes` that you are supposed to `extend`?

Comment: I have Class Binarytree that contain a lot of methods (add, size, isEmpty, counter and getMaxFrequency()), in getMaxFrequency() I have to return the number of the most value is frequent in my test binary tree, I have Node class also. All my methods work fine, but not for getMaxFrequency(). for my test code getMaxFrequency() should return 4 for "java" är most frequent.

Comment: I have BinaryTree and Node Classes, getMaxFrequency() should be in BinaryTree classes that contain a lot of classes.

Comment: Okay, I am working on reading through your code. I'll post a response shortly!

Comment: I am having a lot of fun with this btw! :)

Comment: Is `inorder` required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this for your counter functions:

```
public int counter (T t) {
  if (root == null) return 0;
  
  int count = 0;
  if (root.value.equals(t))
    count++;
  
  count += counterRecursive(root.left, t);
  count += counterRecursive(root.right, t);

  return count;
}

public int counterRecursive (Node<T> root, T t) {
   if (root == null) return 0;
   
   if (root.value.equals(t))
    return 1 + counterRecursive(root.left, t) + counterRecursive(root.right, t);
   else
    return counterRecursive(root.left, t) + counterRecursive(root.right, t);
}
```

The `counter` function looks like the main method to use, and `counterRecursive` is your helper function. More complex recursive solutions typically have this kind of design pattern.

Think in terms of Fibonacci:

```java
public static int fibonacci (int n) {
  return (n <= 1) ? n : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

This should help you debug `inOrder` and `getMaxFrequency`. I would use `counter` in `getMaxFrequency` while I look through the rest. Generally speaking, using a `HashMap` or `HashTable` is much more adequate for keeping track of counts.

Try something like this:

```java
public int getMaxFrequency () {
    if (root == null) return 0;
        
    HashMap<T, Integer> counts = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
        
    int count = counter(root.value);
    counts.put(root.value, count);

    // traverse the tree and grab counts
    int left = getMaxFrequencyHelper(root.left, counts, count);
    int right = getMaxFrequencyHelper(root.right, counts, count);

    return left > right ? left : right;
}

private int getMaxFrequencyHelper (Node<T> node, HashMap<T, Integer> counts, max) {
    if (node == null) return max;

    if (!counts.containsKey(node.value))
        counts.put(node.value, counter(node.value));

    int _max = counts.get(node.value) > max ? counts.get(node.value) : max;

    int left = getMaxFrequencyHelper(node.left, counts, _max);
    int right = getMaxFrequencyHelper(node.right, counts, _max);

    return left > right ? left : right;
}
```

This technique is called `memoization` where the previous counts are `cached` in a `HashMap`.

Comment: Thank you, counter work fine in your way, I wait for getMaxFrequency.

Comment: Is it case sensitive? If it isn't, consider adding everything into your tree as uppercase. That's the standard for SQL, but you can also do all lowercase as well.

Comment: No,the tree not case sensitive, if you mean for methods names or variabels names it is not case sensitive, but if you mean for data type as example String() have to capital letter, I can correct all cases if found, I use Eclipse environmental.

Comment: Sounds good! I just added a solution for the `getMaxFrequency` let me know if you run into any issues.